# Metadata fields not received from azure java sdk on a blob

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

In our Azure portal I have created a storage account and inside created a blob container and inside that a blob which is just a simple text file. I have also set the some random metadata fields on the blob seen here. [image]

In my java code when I access the blob via the Azure SDK I can print the content of the blob, I can acccess the blob properties like the Etag and I can access the container metadata. But I cannot print the blob metadata fields seen above. Specifically this code taken from the samples page doesn't print anything since the received HashMap from `blob.getMetadata()` method is empty.

```
System.out.println("Get blob metadata:"); 
             HashMap<String, String> metadata = blob.getMetadata(); 
             Iterator it = metadata.entrySet().iterator(); 
             while (it.hasNext()) { 
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next(); 
                 System.out.printf(" %s = %s%n", pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()); 
                 it.remove(); 
             }
```

If I instead make a REST API call to the blob and ask for the metadata fields I do get them back as HTTP headers. However I would like to access them via the SDK if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `blob.getMetadata()`, use [blob.downloadAttributes()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/v8.0.0/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.java#L1317)

> This method populates the blob's system properties and user-defined metadata. Before reading or modifying a blob's properties or metadata, call this method or its overload to retrieve the latest values for the blob's properties and metadata from the Microsoft Azure storage service.